# Can I update New in before insert trigger in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example:

```
create table test (id numeric, t date not null);

create trigger test_in
before insert on test
for each row
when New.t is null
begin
 -- set New.t = now();
end;
```

Set New.t didn't work, [where can be only select/insert/update/delete stmt.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)
I can not change the database structure (can set default value).
After insert trigger also not suitable because of "not null" constrain.
The only solution I've found:

```
insert into test values (New.id, now());
select raise(ignore);
```

test database for illustrative purposes only, in practice there are more complicated cases with calculated data. There may be something like this "update New set New.t = now()", or not?

Comment: Can you create a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger and insert into the view instead?

Comment: It's also a variant of the decision, but does not solve the issue. In my case tables are created in synchronization process. I can run any ddl after.

Comment: In main database model also used trigger with set stmt. I can create view, but will have to change and program (if I can...)

Comment: Yes, the select raise(ignore) approach works.

Comment: @Nico it looks like some of the comments have been deleted here, can you please explain the raise(ignore) approach?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't update NEW.

What I tend to do is use a VIEW with an INSTEAD OF trigger as [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) commented above.

In your case the best solution may be to use an AFTER INSERT/UPDATE trigger WHEN NEW.t IS NULL to update t in the affected row(s):

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_in
AFTER INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.t IS NULL)
BEGIN
   UPDATE test SET t = now() WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

FYI, your `id` column should probably be declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY...

Comment: I do not fit this option because of "not null" constrain - insert failed with null :( PS and should not be confused newcomers, better use update ... where rowid = new.rowid

Comment: Well, given that you have this trigger t will not be NULL, so you can drop that constraint.  As for rowid... i hinted at that, but you're right that newcomers might not get the hint.  On the other hand, not all RDBMS always have rowids... Yes, SQLite3 basically always has a rowid, _but_ you can have columns named `rowid` that aren't INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, so I felt it would be safer to recommend that you have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.